# Will 'angular-6-social-login-v2' work in Ionic 3?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Will 'angular-6-social-login-v2'  work in Ionic 3? I need to implement Both Facebook and Google login. Which one is most easy method to implement -

1. Using angular-6-social-login-v2 Node package or,
2. Using Facebook and Google Ionic plugins

If possible can anyone share some demo code links.

Comment: Using Facebook and Google Ionic plugins

Comment: Thank you. I gone with node package and it works well